# How a Muslim state will protect Apostates of other religions?

Tags: sharia, other-religions, apostasy

Islam order killing of converts from Islam or Apostates. What if other religions does the same, how someone will accept Islam? How a Muslim state will protect the Apostates of other religions?

Also what if the same method is applied by other religious state to if someone converts from Islam to their religion?

Comment: I'm not seeing a question here. Besides, killing of apostates is not something scholars agree is Islamic regardless of what extremists might tell you.

Comment: @SystemDown: There are authentic hadith, as well as Ijma of scholars that an apostate should be killed.

Comment: @Farhan - Ijmaa is problematic here since newer scholars have contested the old interpretation of the hadith. This is a comment so I won't elaborate, but newer interpretations say that it isn't the apostate who is killed, but the one who betrays his country (grand treason in today's terms).

Comment: I read that there is death penalty for Apostate on Judaism too

Answer (score 2):

Your question is based on HOW, means its just based on assumption. But we have to live in reality and be realistic in this approach. Currently, no religion has such rulings, other than islam. Even if there is one, then still people WILL keep coming to islam by leaving that certain religion. its not like that if there is a punishment for some act, that means no one does it.